# Rails: Logging for code in the lib directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

What is the best/easiest way to configure logging for code kept in the lib directory?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There's two ways to go about it:

- Assuming your library is self-contained and has a module, you can add a `logger` attribute to your module and use that everywhere in your library code.

  ```
  module MyLibrary
    mattr_accessor :logger
  end
  ```

  You then either use an initializer in `config/initializers/`, or an `config.after_initialize` block in `config/environment.rb` to initialize your logger, like so:

  ```
  require 'mylibrary'
  MyLibrary.logger = Rails.logger
  ```

  This would still allow you to use your self-contained library from scripts outside of Rails. Which is nice, on occasion.
- If using your library without Rails really doesn't make sense at all, then you can also just use `Rails.logger` directly.

In either case, you're dealing with a standard Ruby Logger. Also keep in mind that, in theory, the logger may be `nil`.

Comment: NB: This answer contains incorrect information and editors don't want me to fix them. Unless (perhaps) you're using Rails older than 2.0, you are NOT "dealing with a standard Ruby Logger". Rails now uses [ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/BufferedLogger). If you decide to instantiate a separate logger for (e.g.) a cron job that is contained within a Rails project, to avoid 'polluting' the standard Rails log. In this case, make sure you use `ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new` rather than just `Logger.new`. I tried that and it did not work.

Answer (score 21):

We can use Rails logger directly into the lib, see the following snippet.

```
require 'logger'

Rails.logger.info "Hay..!!! Im in lib"
Rails.logger.debug "Debugging this object from Lib #{object.inspect}"
Rails.logger.error "This is an error..."
```

Comment: This worked for me, finally, after I realized I needed to <require 'logger'>. It's completely obvious, once you know it, but was not obvious to me for a while.

Comment: The downside is that your library code now depends on Rails providing the logger, and cannot be used standalone.