# Wrong logger level in Rails 4 service

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 4 app. In my development.rb config file I have:
config.log_level = :info.

For most of the app it´s working fine showing only info level messages. Queries messages also dissapear, which is ok.

However, I have some services in my lib folder. For them, it looks like it´s not getting the environment log level. This is the code:

```
    @logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join("log", APP_CONFIG['LOG_FILE']))
    if @logger.debug?
      @logger.info "Logger level = debug"
    else
      @logger.info "Logger level > debug"
    end
```

The output:

```
I, [2017-11-10T20:50:51.189067 #36138]  INFO -- : Logger level = debug
```

What am I missing?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2980635/382982

Comment: Yes, but not understand the solution 100%. I think I´m using the first approach but the point is that looks like the logger in the lib is not getting the configuration in production.rb file (which is: config.log_level = :info)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the `.info` method, which results in the log entry being tagged with `INFO`.

Calling `Logger#debug` should result in what (I think) you're expecting to see:

```
@logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join("log", APP_CONFIG['LOG_FILE']))
if @logger.debug?
  @logger.debug "Logger level = debug" # => I, [...]  DEBUG -- : Logger level = debug
else
  @logger.info "Logger level > debug"
end
```

Comment: Nop. I´m calling the info just to display the result. But the point is @logger.debug? is returning true and the output is: Logger level = debug